# How to clean a toilet pan properly?

Tags: cleaning, toilet

What is the best way to clean my dirty toilet pan without damaging the enamel or something else?

[image]

Comment: Your Link isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Efazati provided some good general information on cleaning toilets. For that particular stain, it might go away with some standard cleaners and muscle power, however if it proves to be extra stuborn, use a product designed for deposits like calcium, lime and rust.  A product that comes to mind is [CLR](http://www.jelmar.com/CLRbasic.htm), though there are certainly many other products that accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove items from atop and around the toilet. Clearing items away from the toilet will keep them out of the way and will prevent any accidental drops into the toilet.
2. Wipe down the toilet with a damp sponge. First put on clean gloves. Then moisten a sponge with hot water and wipe around the tank, lid, seat, base, and the exterior of the bowl. This removes excess dirt and helps disperse the cleaning product.
3. Squirt a liquid (cream) toilet cleaner inside the bowl. Squirt the cleaner inside the bowl, starting at the rim and making sure to get the area under the lip of the bowl. Read the manufacturer's instructions first for specific directions. Many cleaners work best if you allow them to soak on the bowl for a while.
4. Scrub the bowl with a toilet brush. Brush the entire bowl thoroughly, paying special attention to mineral stains that may accumulate along the water level and at the back of the bowl. The more thoroughly you scrub the bowl, the cleaner it will get.
5. Flush the toilet. Flushing rinses the bowl and the brush. Continue to scrub as the water drains from the toilet. Repeat several times to thoroughly rinse the bowl and brush.
6. Spray the rest of the toilet with a disinfectant cleaner. Follow the manufacturer's directions. Make sure to get both the top and bottom of the seat, and spray the entire exterior of the toilet. Use a cloth or paper towel to work in, and wipe away, the cleaner
7. Clean the handle thoroughly. Be sure to get the handle with the disinfectant spray. The handle is the primary avenue for the spread of germs, so clean it well.
8. Spray the floor and tiles around the toilet with the disinfectant spray. Wipe clean with paper towels or a cloth.
9. Replace items that were on or around the toilet. Put on clean gloves and rinse off the items that were on or around the toilet. Wipe them dry with a paper towel and put them back in their places.

tips:Paper towels are ideal for cleaning the exterior of the toilet. Since they are disposable, there is a lower risk of spreading germs, and they also absorb the cleaner well and don't leave streaks on the toilet. If you use a cloth, wash it well when you're done, and wash it separately from clothes or other cloths.

from How to Clean a Toilet: 9 steps (with pictures) - wikiHow -> http://www.wikihow.com/Clean-a-Toilet

Comment: Thanks Efazati, but it is the area just under the surface of the water that I need to clean up (you couldn't know that since the picture wasn't working, sorry for that!)

Answer (score 1):

At the golf course I used to work at we would get terrible mineral deposits from the well water.  The only thing we found that worked really well to clean them was ["The Works"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000VM2QBI) toilet bowl cleaner.  It took them right off without much scrubbing.  Be careful though, because the fumes are really strong.